# type 'String?' can't be assigned to type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

Here's my code

Saving String to shared preference

```
if (croppedFile != null) {
      imageFile = croppedFile;
      final bytes = Io.File(imageFile!.path).readAsBytesSync();
      String img64 = base64Encode(bytes);
      setState(() async {
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        prefs.setString('image', img64);
      });
    }
```

Calling shared preference

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                                var iMG = prefs.getString('image');

                                await DatabaseHelper.instance.add(
                                          Cards(
                                              name: NamaKartuController.text,
                                              desc: DescKartuController.text,
                                              iMG : iMG
                                          )
                                );
```

i set it as a `String` but it does still giving -
The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String
Error

Comment: You need to declare your variable as String? IMG. Because your project has null safety enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I think error is in this line. Try to convert this line into string as below-

```
String img64 = base64Encode(bytes).toString();
```

Please let me know the errr again?

Comment: ah yes I just Figure it out a couple second ago ! anyways Thank you

Comment: Please visit flutter tutorials which can help you [Flutter Tutorials](https://www.fluttertpoint.com/category/flutter/). Thankx

Answer (score 1):

`base64Encode(bytes)` Can return null meaning it has a return type of `String?`, and not `String`.

Because `String img64` isn't declared as a nullable variable, it will not accept a value of null. You can change the method call to `base64Encode(bytes)!`, which will assert if the returned value of `base64Encode(bytes)!` is null at runtime.

Simply adding `.toString()` to the existing code doesn't really deal with the issue, as if null is returned from the method, it'll just convert that to the string `"null"`, which feels more like just getting the code to fail silently instead of fixing the issue.

https://dart.dev/codelabs/null-safety